# Is there a vim command to move the cursor to the parent _square_ bracket?

Tags: json, vim

In vim, there are handy commands to move to the nearest enclosing left or right curly brace (`[{` and `]}` respectively).

However, typically when navigating JSON files, it is equally useful to be able to jump to the nearest enclosing *square* bracket. Yet, in the long time I have been wishing for this command, I haven't found it, either built into vim or provided by a plugin. Is it there somewhere?

Comment: how about `/]`?

Comment: Didn't know the answer, but I googled it ... It looks like there's no "built-in" way, but there are some suggestions here: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Jump-to-next-unmatched-square-brackets-td1156241.html -- You could define a key mapping for convenience.

Comment: Wouldn't plain ol' `?\[` do?

Comment: No, in general not. I want to skip any intervening arrays on the same or lower level, e.g. going to the last closing bracket from here:
```
...
  "here": "is my cursor",
  "nested": [
    "is",
    "an",
    "array" ],
   "end": "of the object here"
},
{ "some": "other object" }
]  // here is where I want to go.
```

Comment: @TomLord, that link provides the most comprehensive answers to my question so far. Thanks! (I thought I cannot be the first one to have this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the following two mappings in my vimrc

```
nnoremap ]b :call searchpair('\[','','\]')<cr>
nnoremap [b :call searchpair('\[','','\]','b')<cr>
```

compare also `:h searchpair`. You can change ']b' and '[b' to whatever you like of course.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! This seems more elegant than the solution involving visually highlighting the `[...]` block.

Comment: You can make it even more like `[{` and `[(` by making it silent:
`nnoremap <silent> [b :call searchpair('\[','','\]','b')<cr>`

Answer (score 8):

How about `va[` when you are inside the `[]`. This will visually highlight the enclosed `[]`.  <kbd>Esc</kbd>  takes the cursor on the closing `]`.

To go to opening `[`, Press <kbd>%</kbd>.

Or to shorten it, map it to a key of choice, eg to <kbd>F2</kbd> and save it in vimrc

```
nnoremap <F2> va[<esc>%
```

Comment: That's a good hack!

It even works well with folds (meaning that any `[...]` or `{...}` sub-blocks remain collapsed, only the line that's target of the jump gets uncollapsed).

Comment: If your visual selection is important to maintain, you could also do `"_ya{` to yank the whole block into the blackhole register but this leaves you on the opening brace/bracket instead of the closing one.

Comment: Since I was here last time, I learnt about the visual-mode `o` command that jumps to the other end of the highlighted area. That could be used to simplify the `<esc>%` part I think.